# I can't create a array with objects using map or for

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a number: `totalSupply`.

A function to get address based on this number (vjkNFTContract.ownerOf(i))

and another function to get the data, also based on this number (vjkNFTContract.tokenURI(i)).

I need to create an array with objects [{…}, {…}]

The size of this array should be `totalSupply` and each object should contain the address and the data.

I'm trying something like this:

```
      const structuredCollections = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
          [
            {
              tokenId: i,
              addressSender: vjkNFTContract.ownerOf(i),
              uri: vjkNFTContract.tokenURI(i),
            },
          ];
        }
      };
```

But I'm pretty sure it's wrong.. but I cannot find out...
I'm new to Javascript

Comment: Your title states you can't use a for loop, but your try is using one. Would you like a solution using a for loop?

Comment: You're assigning the array to anything.

Comment: @hamza765 I don't think he means "not allowed to", he means that he's not able to achieve his result using it.

Comment: @hamza765
 Sorry, I'm new here, I don't think I explained it right.

Comment: But anyway our friend @Barmar
 gave me the right answer. Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the objects onto a variable holding the array, then return the array.

```js
const structuredCollections = (totalSupply) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
    result.push({
      tokenId: i,
      addressSender: vjkNFTContract.ownerOf(i),
      uri: vjkNFTContract.tokenURI(i),
    });
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Was about to hit submit on the same exact code. Exactly what I'd do. +1

Comment: awesome.. exactly what I was looking for.. thank...